# Highcharts data from Google spreadsheet show line chart for one series

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

In Excel i was able to draw this chart from data

[Chart Image](http://screencast.com/t/BKeCoL7h)

I want to convert this chart to highcharts. Data is in Google spreadsheet and I am using data module to get data directly from Google spreadsheet and show over chart. Here is code doing it.

```
$('#solar_chart_one').highcharts({
        chart: { type: 'column' },
        data: {
            googleSpreadsheetKey: '0Alz3h5kIx8cWdFNHbmxqbXRILV9kbkd4V0oyX0ZyMWc'
        },

         plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Power Bill Saving Options'
        }
```

});

Here is [JsFiddle for this code](http://jsfiddle.net/sulmanpucit/AYYCv/145/)

Any help on how to make it look alike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the callback function and set the series you want to be a `line` to be a `line` like so:

```
function (chart) {
    chart.series[2].update({
        type: 'line',
        color: 'blue'
    });
}
```

I changed it to also be a blue line.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with working items except for "arrow": http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/E4pSL/